# Google Play update only certain version of Android API

Tags: android, google-play, android-install-apk

If I publish an update of my App (APK) on Google Play version 1.01 for example at the range version of Android API 9 to 23.

And then I find a bug in relation to Android API 14, do an update version 1.2 and at compile time I just to set the API 14 as minimum and maximum.

Who use different Android device for API 14 will see the previous version or will disappear for them?

I wanted to release correction only to users with Android API 14

In some apps like Twitter appears that the version and size of the App depends on the device, would it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your changed configurations for SDK requirements will only apply for the new version.

Existing users will not be able to download the update of their device's api level is out of range of the values you put in your update.

New users will api levels out of range on their device will not be able to download the app. Will get a message saying "This app is not supported on your device"

If your range has increased the supported api levels, you do not need to worry. Existing users will remain unaffected. (they will get an update) New users with added api levels will now be able to download your app.

You can advise users in the "what's new" section if you only want users with a specific api level to update the app. (Mention the android os version and not api level there)

Comment: Hello I wanted to reduce the complaints of many updates

The idea is to fix specific only to a certain version, more apparently does not how to

Thank you

Comment: Per my knowledge there is as of now no way to do it just for a particular api level. But, if your reason for a repeated quick update is justified I dont think users will object. They too want bugs fixed. And if the updated is targeted for specific versions you can state that in the whats new section so that others can ignore the update.

Answer (score 0):

> Who use different Android device for API 14 will see the previous
>   version or will disappear for them?

They will not see your app if you set both minimum and maximum API levels to 14. Publishing and .apk to production replaces the previous one.

You can always roll back to an earlier version though.